# dynamically change css using eval in aspx file

Tags: css, asp.net, eval

Is there a way for me to change the css of an element when I load my data?

I'm trying to load this data, but I don't know how:

```
 <td bgcolor="<%# Eval("connectionMinute") < 120 ? "#FF0000" : "#10FF00" %>" >
```

How do I do this for it to load properly?

Comment: Nope. I didn't use a repeater for this.

Comment: could you add relevant code about your binding? the basic idea is avoid eval. Using an if before tag,  and then set the attr

Comment: Or just cast your dataitem   ((YourClass)Container.DataItem).connectionMinute

Comment: I've decided instead to put one of the values of the 2 colors inside my query, so the data that I throw in the Eval is already the color I intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

It simple.

try this sample code.

create **css** then set class in bind method.

```
 <tr class='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Locked")) ? "class1" : "class2" %>'>
```